# jquery not calling ajax handler

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This should be a really simple fix, but I am pulling my hair out.

This part of the site is really simple. I have a .js file that uses ajax to insert a post into the database when submit is clicked. I get the success part of the jquery, but nothing ever gets put into the database.

Here is the jquery in the $(document).ready(function():

```
   //Button for profile post
        $('#submit_profile_post').click(function(){

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "includes/handlers/ajax_submit_profile_post.php",
                data: $('form.profile_post').serialize(),
                success: function(msg) {
                    $("#post_form").modal('hide');
                    location.reload();
               },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Failure');
                }
            });

        });
```

Here is the ajax handler:

```
<?php  
require '../../config/config.php';
include("../classes/User.php");
include("../classes/Post.php");
include("../classes/Notification.php");
    if(isset($_POST['post_body'])) {
        $post = new Post($con, $_POST['user_from']);
        $post->submitPost($_POST['post_body'], $_POST['user_to']);
    }

    ?>
```

As I said, If I add an alert under the jquery success, I get it just fine but nothing happens after that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you will need to include the content of the php scripts (removing credentials) as well as potentially test the php scripts with different js code to verify that they are working as expected.

Comment: try adding `contentType:'application/json', dataType: "text",`

Comment: is there a request triggered? or you don't get a response..  and which response are you expecting?

Comment: @GeorgeCampbell, PHP does not understand JSON content request bodies out of the box. You have to manually read the raw input in order to get it.

Comment: Is `$_POST['post_body']` set? Can you successfully echo `$_POST['user_from']` on your php page? Does your instantiation of `Post` accept the format in which `$_POST['user_from']` is (unlikely)? Finally, what does your PHP error log say.

Comment: im sure it is easier than you think https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_php.asp

Comment: @GeorgeCampbell I tried adding in the content type and nothing changed.

Comment: try to see what data your php file receives, maybe with ECHO ?

Comment: Tried that and it doesn't echo anything. I even tried to just add an echo saying something random to see if the ajax file is called and nothing. The crazy part is that I added an alert under the success part of the jQuery to make sure that I am getting a success and that works. It is almost as though the connection isn't happening.

Answer (score 0):

Try using FormData

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append('field', value);

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/script.php',
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    type: 'POST',
    `enter code here`
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: did you debug to see the values reaching in your server side php?

Comment: Sorry. I am newer at this. How would I go about doing that? I have tried echoing out the info from the php file but nothing comes out